# How to recover /usr/lib in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, libraries, shared-library

I have situation here, some how on my Ubuntu Box , folder /usr/lib has replaced with /usr/lib_bk but now I am not able to restore it back to original /usr/lib.

I can't really use sudo for my operation as sudoers.so is still being searched in /usr/lib.

Need help as I am not able to use my Ubuntu box.

Comment: If you can't use `sudo` or `pkexec`, then you'll need to boot to a live USB, and then move it.

Comment: What happens if you, in the shell, sets LD_LIBTARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib_bk and the try your sudo command ?